# Pandas: compare two series of arrays with custom comparator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with two series that each contain arrays of strings:

```
   A               B            
0  ['1','2','3']   ['1','2','3']
1  ['1','2','3']   ['1','3','2']
2  ['1','2']       ['1','3']    
3  ['1','2']       ['1']        
4  ['1','2']       ['3']        
5  ['1']           ['2']
```

I want to compare the elements in columns `A` and `B` in a specific way. I want row `C` to be `True` where there is at least 1 element common to both `A` and `B`.

In the example above, I would expect the following:

```
   A               B                  C
0  ['1','2','3']   ['1','2','3']      True
1  ['1','2','3']   ['1','3','2']      True
2  ['1','2']       ['1','3']          True
3  ['1','2']       ['1']              True
4  ['1','2']       ['3']              False
5  ['1']           ['2']              False
```

How can I accomplish this? Pandas does not even allow a straight equality check, as in the following:

```py
df['C'] = df['A'] != df['B']
```

I tried experimenting with `numpy.where()` and `numpy.array_equal()`, but I can't figure out how to use a custom comparator for equality, nor does it seem to compare 2D arrays element-wise.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

---

EDIT: Thanks @Tom and @Erfan for such quick and helpful replies! I will go with the `Series.apply(set)` method for now for readability, unless performance becomes a serious concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your entries were sets instead of lists, you could check if their intersection is.  This is apparently possible by using the `&` operator column-wise (if someone could share documentation on this, that would be appreciated!):

```
>>> df['A'].apply(set) & df['B'].apply(set)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

You could also instead just create a for loop to do this set comparison, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74790376/13386979) and the comment by [Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan):

```
>>> [bool(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
[True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

The latter approach seems to be the quickest on my machine for this example:

```
%%timeit
df['C'] = [bool(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
54.2 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
df['C'] = [bool(len(np.intersect1d(x,y))) for x,y in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
129 µs ± 3.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
df['C'] = df['A'].apply(set) & df['B'].apply(set)
233 µs ± 9.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) with [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#bool) :

```
df["C"] = [bool(len(np.intersect1d(x,y))) for x,y in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
```

Or as suggested by [@Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan), you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) :

```
df["C"] = [bool(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a, b in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

                 A                B      C
0  ['1', '2', '3']  ['1', '2', '3']   True
1  ['1', '2', '3']  ['1', '3', '2']   True
2       ['1', '2']       ['1', '3']   True
3       ['1', '2']            ['1']   True
4       ['1', '2']            ['3']  False
5            ['1']            ['2']  False
```

Comment: +1, curious what the speed comparison is by using just vanilla Python: `[bool(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a, b in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]`

Comment: `79.2 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop` for numpy and `6.9 µs ± 295 ns per loop` for set operation. Do you mind if I add your solution to the answer ?

Comment: Already done by @Tom.

Comment: No ofcourse not! Feel free @abokey

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way would be to use [.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) like so:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].isin(df['B'])
```

This will create a new column, C, that contains *True* for rows where at least one element in column A exists in column B, and *False* otherwise. Checking if A is in B is sufficient, because you are looking for elements that exist in both columns. Therefore you don't have to check the other condition (B in A).

I can't speak of the speed of this operation compared to the other suggested solutions, though.

Comment: This does not work, have you tested your code?